What are 朝元鞋 called in MSM?
Looking at this article, 成都街巷系列（23）——改造前的花牌坊街（五）.
It has the following image and caption:


普通“朝元鞋”一款

These shoes should be a common sight, but what is the name in MSM for 朝元鞋?
朝元鞋 certainly seems to be a topolectical term in Sichuanese. There are even references to the term in 李劼人's《死水微澜》and《大波》. Li Jieren himself is known for pioneering writings in baihua and topolect.
I am sure there are blanket terms like 北京布鞋, etc. but are there any specific terms for this particular shoe?

One of the nicknames for this kind of shoe is 功夫鞋, I call it 黑布鞋

What is MSM? I don't understand it.

@Tom 现代标准汉语 = Modern Standard Mandarin = MSM

@Mou某 Ok, I see.

朝元 is a term in Taoism, so I think this type of shoes derives from the uniform of monks in Sichuan.

在四川等地区叫做朝元鞋和在北京及其周边地区叫做北京布鞋或老北京布鞋的鞋子，再加上在原问题链接中提到的所有黑色面白色鞋底的鞋子 ，其实都是一类鞋子，在现代标准汉语中统称为布鞋，这种布鞋是一种传统的中国鞋类，主要由布料和轻便材料制成，通常有较软的鞋底。
见布鞋的介绍 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%B8%83%E9%9E%8B

Based on the image of the sole, the 朝元鞋 is a variation of the 千层底布鞋 (multi-layered sole cloth shoe). You can see that the sole is multilayered and there're traces of stitching with hemp rope.
There are also other types of cloth shoes, such as 杭元鞋 and 坤尖鞋. We generally refer all these kinds of cloth shoes to simply as 布鞋.
The brand 老北京布鞋 (with 老) are so famous that they are often used to refer to cloth shoes in general, much like how "Google" is synonymous with searching.
However, 朝元鞋 doesn't looks like topolectical term in Sichuan dialect. Take aforementioned 杭元鞋 for example, it literally means small round-toe style of cloth shoes ("小圆口样式的布鞋") produced in Hangzhou. I suspect that 朝元鞋 has a similar meaning, but I'm not an expert in the history of Chinese footwear, so these are just my assumptions.
